# How I can use [String: Any]? for Decodable object?

Tags: swift, struct, codable, decodable

For my response api look like this

```
{
    "properties": {
        "is_enable_widget": true,
        "showing_widget": 10,
        "onboard_time": 5,
        "application_name": "magic_wondering"
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

In field of properties, It have dynamic of number of parameters and dynamic type also.
I declare my object like this

```
struct ConfigurationsModels: Codable {
    let properties: [String: Any]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case properties
    }
}
```

But I got error `Type 'ConfigurationsModels' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`
I have no idea to cast my json to `[String: Any]?`. Has anyone done this before ?

Comment: You need to declare a custom type that holds each of the json keys as properties, there are no shortcuts if you want to conform to Codable

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `Any` with `Codable` , you should use `JSONSerialization` for dynamic value types and keys

```
do { 
   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
         
   }
} catch {
    print(error)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you give me some example from my condition ?

Comment: if you have data from your response then use code above

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom model for your properties. Declare you data models something like this:

```
struct ConfigurationsModels: Codable {
    let properties: Properties
}

struct Properties: Codable {
    let isEnabledWidget: Bool
    let showingWidget: Int
    let onboardTime: Int
    let applicationName: String
    // Add more property here if needed

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isEnabledWidget = "is_enable_widget"
        case showingWidget = "showing_widget"
        case onboardTime = "onboard_time"
        case applicationName = "application_name"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use like that:

```
let properties = try JSONDecoder().decode(ConfigurationsModels.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way will be

Your decodable model (use optionals in property type if it can be avoided from backend)

```swift
struct ResponseModel: Decodable {    
    let properties: Properties
    
    struct Properties: Decodable {
        let isEnableWidget: Bool
        let showingWidget: Int
        let onboardTime: Int
        let applicationName: String       
    }
}
```

Your decoder, using keyDecodingStrategy your be able not to implement `enum CodingKeys`

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let model = try? decoder.decode(ResponseModel.self, from: data)decoder.decode(ResponseModel.self, from: data)
```